# Comprobar que hay una palabra en un div y entonces cambiar su clase

Tags: javascript, jquery

Supongamos que tengo un div con una cadena de caracteres y quiero ver si existe una palabra en concreto y hacer algo:

```
$('.container-text:contains("text")').addClass('container-text-right');
```

Pero cómo verifico si quiero que compruebe más de una palabra y que entonces haga algo según cierta condición? por ejemplo...

```
if($('.container-text:contains("texto1")')){
  $('.container-text').addClass('container-text-right');
   // y hacer algo más
} else if ($('.container-text:contains("texto2")')){
  $('.container-text').addClass('container-text-right');
  // y hacer algo más
}
```

Así es como quiero comprobarlo pero no doy con ello, que me decís?

Comment: si quieres comprobar más de una condición no hagas if anidados con if - else sino if independientes así pasará por todas las comprobaciones, de la otra forma sólo comprobará hasta que encuentre una coincidencia

Comment: Si, eso también lo he probado pero de ambas formas no consigo que me añada esa clase... u haga otras coas. Me sigue dejando el 'container-text' a secas sin añadirme la nueva.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No comprendo muy bien tu idea, pero lo que quieres hacer, puedes hacerlo comprobando la longitud de la cadena que buscas:

```js
if($(".container-text:contains('Hola')").length > 0){
  $( ".container-text:contains('Hola')" ).addClass("cambio1");
}

if($(".container-text:contains('Mundo')").length > 0){
  $( ".container-text:contains('Mundo')" ).addClass("cambio");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Contains</title>
</head>
<body>
  <style>
    .cambio{
      color:#0f0;
    }
    .cambio1{
      text-decoration:underline;
    }
  </style>
  <div class="container-text">Hola</div>
  <div class="container-text">Mundo</div>
  <div class="container-text">Mundo!</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Estupendo, ésto era más o menos lo que necesitaba, toquiteando algo más, muchas gracias!.

Comment: Que curioso, me copio éstos códigos en un html desde mi editor, y no me hace los pertinentes cambios... A que puede ser debido?.

Comment: si estas colocando el codigo javascript entre etiquetas `<script></script>`?

Comment: Claro jeje pero no hace el cambio ni hace nada, solo texto uno encima de otro como muestras pero no cambia la clase. Cargué otro jquery por si acaso, e igualmente tampoco

Comment: Está raro, si aquí funciona debería correr sin problemas en tu propio código, copiaste tal como está el codigo aqui?

Comment: Si, creé con el visual studio una página html, creé las etiquetas en el head para meter ahí los estilos, unas etiquetas para el script, además de cargar la librería Jquery, es decir, los mismos pasos que cualquier web.

Comment: los estilos colocalos al inicio despues de abrir la etiqueta body, y los scripts antes del cierre de la etiqueta body, para que se cargue todo el dom y luego se ejecuten los scripts.

Answer (score 2):

concatenar los `contains` de la siguiente forma

```
/* , el operador , funciona como un or */
$("div:contains('texto1'), div:contains('texto2'), div:contains('texto3')")
/* la concatenación como el AND */
$("div:contains('texto1'):contains('texto2'):contains('texto3')")
```

El código final quedaría así , teniendo en cuenta que en lugar de `css` seria `addClass`

```js
$(".field:contains('Hola'):contains('Mundo')").css('background', 'yellow');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Contains</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="field"> 
   Hola Mundo
</div>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </body>
 </html>
```