# Aplicar un estilo leyendo el contenido de un div

Tags: javascript, estilos

Os comento lo que quiero hacer y a ver si me podéis echar una mano. Yo tengo una web que lee los datos que tengo en un servidor. Lo que quiero hacer es que, según la lectura del contenido aplique un color u otro. Por ejemplo, si lee "Disponible" que aplique el color verde, pero quiero que se realice a la carga de la página.
He hecho varios intentos donde he sido capaz de que por clase cambie el color del div. Haciendo eso intenté, dentro del bucle for que recorre todos los div introducir un if con la condición de que la lectura fuera correcta. Para ello hice que la lectura de la variable en los div se guardara en una variable en cada ciclo del bucle for. Luego comprobaba que fuera "==true" y, si ese era el caso, aplicara al div con el índice correspondiente del array el estilo. Pero no conseguí que funcionara.
Dejo por aquí el código del Script:

```
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
 var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("prueba");
 for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){       
   let validacion = elements[i].includes("prueba");
   if ("validacion" == "true"){
     elements[i].style.backgroundColor="#FD990B";      
   }
  }
 }
```

Además de eso intenté también hacerlo de la siguiente forma que vi en otro post de la web:

```
if($(".prueba:contains('prueba')").length > 0){
  $( ".prueba:contains('prueba')" ).addClass("prueba1");
}
```

Hice literalmente lo que pone en este [post](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/25914/comprobar-que-hay-una-palabra-en-un-div-y-entonces-cambiar-su-clase?newreg=1d120f0fed2c47eaa883e0769fc2c436) pero no me ha funcionado.
¿Podríais echarme una mano con esto? Muchas gracias de antemano por vuestro tiempo.

Comment: Yo cambiaria esta línea `if ("validacion" == "true")` ya que no es lo mismo la variable validacion a la cadena "validacion" y "true" no es igual que true.

Comment: @GmrYael Lo acabo de hacer pero no cambia el resultado, o sea, seguro que tienes razón pero no ha funcionado. Muchas gracias por responder, de verdad (no me esperaba respuesta alguna, sinceramente).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes validar el texto contenido dentro del elemento y para ello puedes emplear `textContent`:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('prueba');
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    let validacion = elements[i].textContent.includes('prueba');
    if (validacion) {
      elements[i].style.backgroundColor = '#FD990B';
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.prueba {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="prueba">prueba</div>
  <div class="prueba">no contiene</div>
  <div class="prueba">no contiene</div>
  <div class="prueba">prueba</div>
  <div class="prueba">prueba</div>
  <div class="prueba">no contiene</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Mil gracias! De verdad <3